# Usage of yet in present perfect sentence in a negative way

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Which one is correct?

1. I haven't yet received the email.
2. I haven't received the email yet.

I am not sure which one is correct. I have seen type 2 being used but I want to clarify whether type 1 is correct or not?

Comment: Just between us, leaving out the cranky *yet* may get better results. You didn't receive the email you want and expect. We get that. Your reader will always introduce a tone of voice to understand what you're really saying.

Comment: _Yet_ is a negative polarity item, so it **has to** be "in a negative way". Without the negative it's ungrammatical in either position. With the negative, _yet_ can go in either position. Why did you think one way was incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Both are correct.

Example of the first form:

> He hasn't yet received his due

https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/art/great-works/great-works-a-complete-new-system-of-midwifery-1751-george-stubbs-1923472.html

Example of the second form:

> He hasn't received his invitation yet

[https://www.theguardian.com/film/2003/feb/21/artsfeatures.television#:~:text=He%20hasn't%20received%20his%20invitation%20yet%2C%20and%20doesn't%20know%20if%20he'll%20have%20to%20part%20with%20any%20money.%20](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2003/feb/21/artsfeatures.television#:%7E:text=He%20hasn%27t%20received%20his%20invitation%20yet%2C%20and%20doesn%27t%20know%20if%20he%27ll%20have%20to%20part%20with%20any%20money.%20)